# How to have exit code of container for task can be captured

Tags: python, shell, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a airflow dag with 2 different tasks, and I want the second task to be giving the failure or passing based on the container exit, where the failure will be exit 1 and passed with exit 0.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

docker container wait container-name

And in case the output of above command is 0 its ok, but if its 1 then the job needs to fail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well I was able to accomplish this through docker wait command